# Trouble getting into json data object

Tags: json, reactjs, state

I have some code that allows the user to click a image to then update the page and display the clicked on champions name. the json data looks like this -http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/Alistar.json

I console.log response.data and see a object of objects and am wondering how to get passed the section that has the response.data.(whatever champion the user picked). I have tried adding a variable like response.data.champion but I assume no variables can be passed like that seeing how it doesnt work.

Not sure if its even worth posting the code but just in case! My code is below, the fetch im trying to go through is in NewChamp function.
To make my request simpler, All i want to know for example is how i would get response.data.(whatever the user clicked).key from any possible champion clicked like http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/Alistar.json or http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/Anivia.json
or whatever other champion the user clicks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Champions.css';





class AllChamps extends Component  {

 render() {
let champion = this.props.champion;
        return(  
        <div className='champions'>
            <h1> all champions</h1>
            {Object.keys(this.props.champions).map((s) => (
                <div className='champs'     onClick={() => this.props.NewChamp({s, champion})}>        
                    <img   
                        alt='Champion Images'
                        src={`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/img/champion/${s}.png`}
                        onClick={this.props.onClick}
                     ></img>     
                    {s} 
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
)}}


class SpecificChamp extends Component  {

    render() {
       let champion = this.props.champion
       let Spec = champion[champion.length - 1];
        return (
            <div className='champions'>
                <h1> 1 champions</h1>
                <div className='champs'>
                    <button    onClick={this.props.onClick}></button>
                    {Spec}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
}




class Champions extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleAllChamps = this.handleAllChamps.bind(this);
        this.handleSpecificChamp = this.handleSpecificChamp.bind(this);
        this.NewChamp = this.NewChamp.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            champions: [],
            champion: [],
            clickedChamp: false,
            thisChamp: 'ahri'
        }}
NewChamp = (props) =>
 {
 let  s = props.s;
 props.champion.push(s);


fetch(`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/${s}.json`)
    .then(response => { return response.json() })
    .then((response) => {
        Object.keys(response.data).map((a) => (s = a
        ))})
        fetch(`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/${s}.json`)
            .then(response => { return response.json() })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(s)
                console.log(response.data)

                console.log(props.champion)

                
                
        })
        console.log(`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/${s}.json`);

      

        

}

    handleAllChamps = (props) => {
        this.setState({ clickedChamp: true,
           })};
  
    handleSpecificChamp = () => {
        this.setState({ clickedChamp: false,
          })};

    componentDidMount(props) {
        const apiUrl = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion.json`;
        fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(response => { return response.json() })
          .then((response) => {
          this.setState({
              champions: response.data
             
          }, () => (this.state.champions))
      
          return  
      })
   
  }

    render() {
   
        const clickedChamp = this.state.clickedChamp;
        let display;
        if (clickedChamp ) {
            display = <SpecificChamp champion={this.state.champion} onClick={this.handleSpecificChamp} s={this.state.thisChamp}/>;
        } else {
            display = <AllChamps  champions={this.state.champions} onClick={this.handleAllChamps}  NewChamp={this.NewChamp} thisChamp={this.state.thisChamp} champion={this.state.champion} />;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='champions'></div>

                {display}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Champions;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is in the form of Object of Objects. You've to use JSON.stringify(response.data) in order to view the entire data as a string in the debug console.

You will have to destructure the Object of objects.

Object.keys(response.data).map((key)=> console.log(response.data[key]))

In this case if it is just one key

```
response.data[s]
```

Comment: thank you so much! looks like [] alows me to use the variable s. you the true mvp